# Cairo::SolidPattern is not of type GooCanvas2::CairoPattern

Tags: perl, gtk3, cairo, gobject-introspection

I'm trying to convert old Gtk2 perl script to Gtk3. Here is how the Gtk2 version looks like:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.30.0;
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use Gtk2 '-init';
use Goo::Canvas;

my $canvas = Goo::Canvas->new;
my $pattern = Cairo::SolidPattern->create_rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
$pattern = Goo::Cairo::Pattern->new($pattern);

my $rect = Goo::Canvas::Rect->new(
    $canvas->get_root_item,
    0, 0, 100, 100,
    'fill-pattern' => $pattern,
    'line-dash'    => Goo::Canvas::LineDash->new([5, 5]),
    'line-width'   => 1,
    'stroke-color' => 'black',
);
```

This is my Gtk3 attempt:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.30.0;
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use Gtk3 '-init';
use GooCanvas2;

my $canvas = GooCanvas2::Canvas->new;
my $pattern = Cairo::SolidPattern->create_rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

my $rect = GooCanvas2::CanvasRect->new(
    parent => $canvas->get_root_item,
    x => 0, y => 0, width => 100, height => 100,
    'fill-pattern' => $pattern,
    'line-dash'    => GooCanvas2::CanvasLineDash->newv([5, 5]),
    'line-width'   => 1,
    'stroke-color' => 'black',
);
```

But this results in error:

```
Uncaught exception from user code:
    Cairo::SolidPattern=SCALAR(0x558de4acb260) is not of type GooCanvas2::CairoPattern at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.30.1/x86_64-linux/Glib.pm line 222.
    Glib::Object::_LazyLoader::AUTOLOAD("GooCanvas2::CanvasRect", "parent", GooCanvas2::CanvasGroup=HASH(0x558de4abe1a0), "x", 0, "y", 0, "width", ...) called at test.pl line 14
```

I also tried to insert `$pattern = GooCanvas2::CairoPattern->new($pattern);` but that didn't help:

```
Uncaught exception from user code:
    Could not fetch information for package GooCanvas2::CairoPattern; perhaps it has not been loaded via Glib::Object::Introspection? at test.pl line 13.
```

But looking at source of `GooCanvas2.pm`, it does load `GooCanvas2` via Glib::Object::Introspection.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to install [libgoocanvas-2.0-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libgoocanvas-2.0-dev) on Ubuntu 20.04 and it installs the introspection XML file for GooCanvas as `/usr/share/gir-1.0/GooCanvas-2.0.gir`. In this file I see the definition for the binding for `GooCanvas2::CanvasRect->new()`:

```
<class name="CanvasRect"
       c:symbol-prefix="canvas_rect"
       c:type="GooCanvasRect"
       parent="CanvasItemSimple"
       glib:type-name="GooCanvasRect"
       glib:get-type="goo_canvas_rect_get_type"
       glib:type-struct="CanvasRectClass">
  <implements name="CanvasItem"/>
  <function name="new"
            c:identifier="goo_canvas_rect_new"
            introspectable="0">
    <return-value transfer-ownership="full">
      <type name="CanvasItem" c:type="GooCanvasItem*"/>
    </return-value>
    <parameters>
      <parameter name="parent" transfer-ownership="none" skip="1">
        <type name="CanvasItem" c:type="GooCanvasItem*"/>
      </parameter>
      <parameter name="x" transfer-ownership="none">
        <type name="gdouble" c:type="gdouble"/>
      </parameter>
      <parameter name="y" transfer-ownership="none">
        <type name="gdouble" c:type="gdouble"/>
      </parameter>
      <parameter name="width" transfer-ownership="none">
        <type name="gdouble" c:type="gdouble"/>
      </parameter>
      <parameter name="height" transfer-ownership="none">
        <type name="gdouble" c:type="gdouble"/>
      </parameter>
      <parameter name="..." transfer-ownership="none">
        <varargs/>
      </parameter>
    </parameters>
  </function>
```

I notice that the definition for the `fill-pattern` parameter is probably included in the last `name="..."` parameter pack. So it is not clear what type the parameter should be. But later in the file there is maybe a clue, on line 244 we have:

```
<glib:boxed glib:name="CairoPattern"
            c:symbol-prefix="cairo_pattern"
            glib:type-name="GooCairoPattern"
            glib:get-type="goo_cairo_pattern_get_type">
</glib:boxed>
```

I am not sure what exactly the `glib:boxed` means, but according to the documentation for [Glib::Object::Introspection](https://metacpan.org/pod/Glib::Object::Introspection) :

> Classes, interfaces and boxed and fundamental types get their own
> namespaces, in a way, as the concept of the GType is completely
> replaced in the Perl bindings by the Perl package name.

So `boxed` types get their own namespace in Perl. More about boxed types [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Boxed-Types.html).

The error message:

```
Cairo::SolidPattern=SCALAR(0x55a027382d18) is not of type GooCanvas2::CairoPattern ...
```

Indicates that it expects a `GooCanvas2::CairoPattern` type, but when I try to use such a type, e.g.

```
my $pattern = GooCanvas2::CairoPattern->new();
```

I get error message:

```
Could not fetch information for package GooCanvas2::CairoPattern; perhaps it has not been loaded via Glib::Object::Introspection?
```

**Update**:

The following C program works fine and shows that the pattern should be of type `cairo_pattern_t` :

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <goocanvas.h>

static gboolean
on_delete_event (GtkWidget *window,
                 GdkEvent  *event,
                 gpointer   unused_data)
{
    exit (0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 640, 600);
    g_signal_connect (window, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK (on_delete_event), NULL);
    GtkWidget *scrolled_win = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL, NULL);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), scrolled_win);
    GtkWidget *canvas = goo_canvas_new();
    goo_canvas_set_bounds (GOO_CANVAS (canvas), 0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    GooCanvasItem *root = goo_canvas_get_root_item (GOO_CANVAS (canvas));
    cairo_pattern_t *pattern = cairo_pattern_create_rgba( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5 );
    GooCanvasItem *rect = goo_canvas_rect_new(
        root, 0, 0, 100, 100,
        "line-width", 1.0,
        "stroke-color", "black",
        "fill-pattern", pattern,
        NULL
    );
    gtk_widget_set_size_request (canvas, 600, 450);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (scrolled_win), canvas);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

**Update 2**:

Some more debugging info: The call `GooCanvas2::CanvasRect->new()` is redirected to [line 1327](https://metacpan.org/source/XAOC/Glib-1.3293/GObject.xs#L1327) in `GObject.xs`:

```
SV *
g_object_new (class, ...)
   // ...
```

at [line 1359](https://metacpan.org/source/XAOC/Glib-1.3293/GObject.xs#L1359) it finds the expected type for the property argument `fill-pattern`. It looks like this is type [G_TYPE_BOXED](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gobject/gtype.h#L166). Then at [line 1378](https://metacpan.org/source/XAOC/Glib-1.3293/GObject.xs#L1378)

```
gperl_value_from_sv (&params[i].value, ST (FIRST_ARG+i*2+1));
```

It tries to retrieve the boxed value from the supplied Perl argument (of type `Cairo::SolidPattern`) which leads to [line 136](https://metacpan.org/source/XAOC/Glib-1.3293/GValue.xs#L136)

```
    case G_TYPE_BOXED:
        /* SVs need special treatment! */
        if (G_VALUE_HOLDS (value, GPERL_TYPE_SV)) {
            g_value_set_boxed (value,
                               gperl_sv_is_defined (sv)
                               ? sv : NULL);
        } else {
            g_value_set_static_boxed (
                value,
                gperl_get_boxed_check (
                    sv, G_VALUE_TYPE(value)));
        }
```

The first check fails so it enters the second alternative `g_value_set_static_boxed()` which first calls `gperl_get_boxed_check()`, see [line 558](https://metacpan.org/source/XAOC/Glib-1.3293/GBoxed.xs#L558) in `GBoxed.xs`. On line 568

```
boxed_info = g_hash_table_lookup (info_by_gtype, (gpointer) gtype);
```

`boxed_info` is returned as `BoxedInfo *` with content

```
{
  gtype = 93825018188384,
  package = 0x555556e4e7a0 "GooCanvas2::CairoPattern",
  wrapper_class = 0x0
}
```

and at line 575 `unwrap` is set to `_default_wrapper_class.unwrap` and at line 583:

```
return (*unwrap) (gtype, boxed_info->package, sv);
```

which calls `default_boxed_unwrap()` at [line 420](https://metacpan.org/source/XAOC/Glib-1.3293/GBoxed.xs#L420) :

which croaks at line 429:

```
if (!sv_derived_from (sv, package))
    croak ("%s is not of type %s",
           gperl_format_variable_for_output (sv),
           package);
```

since `Cairo::SolidPattern` is not derived from `GooCanvas2::CairoPattern`.

**Update 3**:

Looking at [GooCanvas's source](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/goocanvas/-/blob/f8d9feeaae7eed42002475e73afc5bf515a89b0c/src/goocanvasitemsimple.c), it defines several setters/getters for the pattern: `fill-color`, `fill-color-rgba`, `fill-color-gdk-rgba`, `fill-pixbuf`, `fill-pattern`, all of which internally set/get the same property `goo_canvas_style_fill_pattern_id`. And other setters don't have the issue of having the wrong introspection wrapper to `cairo_pattern_t`. Therefore this works:

```
my $rect = GooCanvas2::CanvasRect->new(
  ...
  'fill-color-gdk-rgba' => Gtk3::Gdk::RGBA::parse('red'),
);
```

Moreover, after `$rect` is constructed, we can get `GooCanvas2::CairoPattern` from it via `$rect->get('fill-pattern')`.

This doesn't let use other patterns created from cairo (linear, etc), but at least solid color works by providing arbitrary RGBA, and pixbuf setter should be enough for other needs.

**Update 4**:

I wrote [GooCanvas2::CairoTypes](https://metacpan.org/pod/GooCanvas2::CairoTypes) to work this around at least for Patterns.

It uses `gperl_register_boxed_synonym(CAIRO_GOBJECT_TYPE_PATTERN, GOO_TYPE_CAIRO_PATTERN);` to let `Cairo::Pattern` be used as `GooCanvas::CairoPattern`, and additionally provides a function to explicitly convert `GooCanvas::CairoPattern` to `Cairo::Pattern` via `gperl_new_boxed(gperl_get_boxed_check(input, GOO_TYPE_CAIRO_PATTERN), CAIRO_GOBJECT_TYPE_PATTERN, 0)`.

Comment: Re "*the pattern should be of type cairo_pattern_t*", Yeah, but `typedef cairo_pattern_t GooCairoPattern`. That's where the GooCanvas2::CairoPattern name from the error message comes from. From what I can tell, the aliases is for autodocumentation tools and/or whatever creates that .gir file.

Comment: I think that boxed is an external type, something that would be provided by another module.

Comment: `cairo_pattern_t` is provided by an include from `libcairo2-dev`. That package doesn't install a `.gir` file.

Comment: On my system there is a `cairo-1.0.gir` file, but it's provided by `dev-libs/gobject-introspection` package instead of cairo itself. But that file seems to be hand-written, it doesn't even contain `create_rgba`, and defines this: `<record name="Pattern" c:type="cairo_pattern_t" foreign="1" glib:type-name="CairoPattern" glib:get-type="cairo_gobject_pattern_get_type"/>`

Comment: Looking at the goocanvasitemsimple.c I figured out what to do here, though the solution here is specific to the GooCanvas2 library. I'll edit the answer

Comment: I sent https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/goocanvas/-/merge_requests/9 upstream - if/when it gets merged, I'll update the answer

Comment: And... done! Not the way I was hoping though.